# Problens quotes redhat openshift

Tags: mysql, openshift, hosting, redhat

I try to deploy an application on [OpenShift](https://www.openshift.com/) and I always get this message:

> FailedCreate: checkapi-14 Error creating: pods "checkapi-14-" is forbidden: 
>        [minimum cpu usage per Pod is 19m, but request is 12m., minimum memory 
>        usage per Pod is 100Mi, but request is 67108864., minimum cpu usage per 
>        Container is 19m, but request is 12m., minimum memory usage per Container 
>        is 100Mi, but request is 64Mi.]

Could you tell me why please?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using OpenShift Online, this suggests you have overridden the memory resources limit values and have made it too small. The minimum you can set memory to is 256MB.

The reason I am talking about memory rather than CPU is that in OpenShift Online, the CPU is calculated in proportion to memory, you can't control CPU yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot Graham